Can't commit to github using python
I want to make a commit to github (via my personal gihub account) using a python script.
I've created a new git repo via chrome and made sure it's empty (called test_repo)
I run main.py as shown bellow but get the following error message when it runs:
Failed to create commit: 409 {"message":"Git Repository is empty.","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/git/commits#create-a-commit"}

My guess would be that I am adding text to a file without having created the file yet ... should I first create the file then add text ... if so that would be 2 commits not 1 ... seems kinda extra?

cryptographer.py is a python file that helps me securely store my github token
main.py
import requests
import cryptographer

def create_commit(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, commit_message, file_changes, access_token, headers):
    # 1. Authentication
    headers['Authorization'] = f'token {access_token}'
    new_repo = repo_is_empty(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, access_token, headers)
    if not new_repo:
        commit_data = {
            'message': commit_message,
            'tree': create_tree(repo_owner, repo_name, file_changes, access_token, headers),
            'parents': [get_latest_commit_sha(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, access_token, headers)]
        }
    else:
        commit_data = {
            'message': commit_message,
            'tree': None  # No need to specify a tree for the initial commit
        }
    # 2. Create a New Commit Object

    response = requests.post(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/commits', headers=headers, json=commit_data)
    if response.status_code == 201:
        commit_sha = response.json()['sha']
        update_branch_reference(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, commit_sha, access_token, headers)
        print("Commit created successfully!")
    else:
        print("Failed to create commit:", response.status_code, response.text)


def create_tree(repo_owner, repo_name, file_changes, access_token, headers):
    headers['Authorization'] = f'token {access_token}'
    tree_data = []
    for file_change in file_changes:
        tree_data.append({
            'path': file_change['path'],
            'mode': '100644',  # File mode
            'type': 'blob',    # Object type: blob for file
            'content': file_change['content']
        })

    tree_payload = {
        'tree': tree_data
    }

    url = f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/trees'
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=tree_payload)

    if response.status_code == 201:
        return response.json()['sha']
    else:
        print("Failed to create tree:", response.status_code, response.text)
        return None

def repo_is_empty(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, access_token, headers) -> bool:
    headers['Authorization'] = f'token {access_token}'
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/ref/heads/{branch}', headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 409:
        return True
    print("Failed to check if repo is empty:", response.status_code, response.text)
    return False

def get_latest_commit_sha(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, access_token, headers):
    headers['Authorization'] = f'token {access_token}'
    response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/ref/heads/{branch}', headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()['object']['sha']
    else:
        print("Failed to get latest commit SHA:", response.status_code, response.text)
        return None

def update_branch_reference(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, commit_sha, access_token, headers):
    headers['Authorization'] = f'token {access_token}'
    ref_payload = {
        'sha': commit_sha,
        'force': True
    }

    response = requests.patch(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/git/refs/heads/{branch}', headers=headers, json=ref_payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Failed to update branch reference:", response.status_code, response.text)

# Example usage
repo_owner: str = REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
repo_name = 'test_repo'
branch = 'main'
commit_message = 'Test commit via Python'
file_changes = [
    {
        'path': 'example.txt',
        'content': 'Hello, world!'
    }
]
access_token = cryptographer.Encrypter.get_token()
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
}
create_commit(repo_owner, repo_name, branch, commit_message, file_changes, access_token, headers)

I made sure that the user existed using is_valid_username() and the token is fresh (generated a few days ago - should last for 90 says). I can't find what error code 409 means other then "the request wasn't completed because of a conflict with the resource's current state" but I don't really get what that means.
def is_valid_username(username: str) -> bool:
    url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{username}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return True
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        return False
    else:
        raise UnknownErrorCodeException(f"Request to find user failed. Github err: {response.status_code}", response.status_code)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

That's not too far from what I'm looking for although they are using curl and I feel like that would be out of place in python. I'll try to convert that code to python and see if that works for me. Thank you for your help!
